# Python Pandas dataframe column not update correctly on Split data fraction

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, split

I have a Python function to split data, that is formatted as a fraction: 4/5, 1/1, 1,2, etc. This function iterates thru the dataframe ok. the split() function. The print() statements shows correct split on variable s[0] and s[1], respectively. The problem is that the df_ff_reviews['NumHelpfulVotes'] = s[0] and df_ff_reviews['NumVotes'] = s[1] dataframe columnes are not updated with the split value of the s[0], s[1], respectively. When I view the dataframe (head) I see all rows for columns NumHelpfulVotes and NumVotes which are set to zero. Never matching the s[0] and s[1] split values inside the iterated loop.

```
def split_votes():
    for idx, row in df_ff_reviews.iterrows():
        value = ''
        s = ''
        value = str(row['helpfulness'])
        s = value.split('/')
        df_ff_reviews['NumHelpfulVotes'] = s[0]           
        df_ff_reviews['NumVotes'] = s[1]

s[0]): 0
s[1]): 1
s[0]): 19
s[1]): 19
s[0]): 13
s[1]): 13
s[0]): 9
s[1]): 9
s[0]): 3
s[1]): 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing like `str.split` with `expand`

```
df_ff_reviews[['NumHelpfulVotes','NumVotes']]=df_ff_reviews.helpfullness.str.split('/',expand=True)[[0,1]]
```